# Emacs No-Window goes into an infinite loop

Tags: emacs, window, infinite-loop, freeze

I remote into a linux machine from cygwin on windows7 via ssh -Y.

Once ssh completes, if I execute emacs the usual way (`emacs`), everything works fine. If I try to execute it in the console (i.e. via `emacs -nw`), it loads scratch buffer and hangs, without reacting to any keys. On `top` I see that it uses 100% of CPU, which never happened to my emacs before.

The same setup works ok on other Linux machines (same profile, same bash, same command sequence). I don't even have an idea what can be wrong. Could someone please help?

Thank you very much.

**Edit** XEmacs worked fine.

Comment: Standard debugging technique is to start emacs with -q to not read in your .emacs file which may be the source of the pain.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @EricJohnson didn't know - trying now

Comment: @EricJohnson Same thing happened, but the buffer it pulled up was different. Still pulled up the buffer and went into infinite loop.

Comment: sorry... out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalled emacs, it worked. Still not sure what was wrong...